# How to sanitize user output properly

Tags: php, security, layout, sanitization

So, I'm working on a website where people can create threads and responses to them.
So far, before saving the data into the database I

- use **mysql_real_escape_string** to sanitize the data
- check the number of lines that the text (it must be lower than a
  given maximum number, for example 10 lines at most)

And before displaying it on screen I

- use **htmlentities** to sanitize the HTML data
- use **nl2br** to allow line breaks
- use **wordwrap** to word wrapping the text (the line must have at most 75
  characters)

Is there anything else that a malicious user could do to make problems or break the layout? And is there any special ASCII code that could cause problems? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Another thing that I can think of is: if your database input is a number, do an is_numeric check on it (or some other check if it is a fractional number).

It can be a valid string, but it will break your query despite using mysql_real_escape_string (assuming you are using the mysql api and not the mysqli api).

Comment: Ah, yes, but in this case it's not necessary numerical. I didn't know, though, that non-numeric values in numeric fields could break the query. I thought that it just saved a 0 in that field. So thanks for the info

Answer (score 1):

The one thing you're missing is validating untrusted data against a whiltelist. mysql_real_escape_string will *escape* the data but that could still be data you don't want in the system. You're better off describing what you *will* allow and rejecting or removing anything else before escaping.

Refer to OWASP whitelist sanitisation: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Data_Validation#Sanitize_with_Whitelist